# indexOutOfBoundsException with arraylists deletion

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I am writing a space invaders knock off in java and I am almost done the actual working parts but I keep on getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:492)
at GamePanel.shotDelete(SpaceInvaders.java:261)
at GamePanel.shieldHit(SpaceInvaders.java:198)
at SpaceInvaders.actionPerformed(SpaceInvaders.java:44)
at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:313)
at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:245)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I know this has been asked before but no one wants to solve it. My code that this error is thrown at is:

```
public void shieldHit(){
    //enemy shots
    ArrayList<Integer>usedBadShot=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int b=0;b<badShotList.size();b++){
        for(int i=0;i<shieldShape.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<shieldShape[i].length;j++){
                if(shieldShape[i][j]==1){
                    int xc=shieldLocX+j*6;
                    int yc=375+i*6;
                    if(badShotList.get(b)[x]<=xc+6&&badShotList.get(b)[x]>=xc&&badShotList.get(b)[y]<=yc+6&&badShotList.get(b)[y]>=yc){
                        //delete hit block
                        shieldShape[i][j]=0;

                        //randomly delete left or right of spot
                        int randint=(int)(Math.random()*101);
                        if(randint<=33){
                            shieldShape[i][j+1]=0;
                        }
                        else if(randint>33&&randint<67){
                            shieldShape[i][j-1]=0;
                        }
                        usedBadShot.add(b);
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
    for(int i=0;i<usedBadShot.size();i++){
        badShotDelete(usedBadShot.get(i));
    }
    //user shots
    ArrayList<Integer>usedShot=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int b=0;b<shotList.size();b++){
        for(int i=0;i<shieldShape.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<shieldShape[i].length;j++){
                if(shieldShape[i][j]==1){
                    int xc=shieldLocX+j*6;
                    int yc=375+i*6;
                    if(shotList.get(b)[x]<=xc+6&&shotList.get(b)[x]>=xc&&shotList.get(b)[y]<=yc+6&&shotList.get(b)[y]>=yc){
                        //delete hit block
                        shieldShape[i][j]=0;

                        //randomly delete left or right of spot
                        int randint=(int)(Math.random()*101);
                        if(randint<=33){
                            shieldShape[i][j+1]=0;
                        }
                        else if(randint>33&&randint<67){
                            shieldShape[i][j-1]=0;
                        }
                        usedShot.add(b);
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
    for(int i=0;i<usedShot.size();i++){
        shotDelete(usedShot.get(i));
    }
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When removing elements from `ArrayList` it's better to make it from the end to the start. This way, the used index in the for loop will not come into index which are can't be use anymore due to removed data.

Comment: I edited my code to now look like this `
  for(int i=usedBadShot.size()-1;i>0;i--){
   badShotDelete(usedBadShot.get(i));
  }...
  for(int i=usedShot.size()-1;i>0;i--){
   shotDelete(usedShot.get(i));
  }`but it now allows the shots to fly right through the barriers without being removed. Please help

Comment: I just fixed it, just needed an if statement to make sure that the index is greater than 1 so I can subtract 1 from it. Thank you fir your help